# Is there anything for subversion as gerrit for git?

Tags: git, svn, gerrit

Gerrit is useful but it's only for git. I want to setup something like it, but for subversion. Is there any software doing this job?

Comment: Gerrit was inspired by rietveld, which only supported Subversion. Never used it, link is here: http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/

Comment: There is even a person named Gerrit Rietveld who was a Dutch furniture designer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For which part: code review or hosting or both?

For code reviews, [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/) works well.  It's not perfect, but I've used it to great success on a couple of projects.  It doesn't deal at all with hosting or access controls though.

For hosting, you might try [usvn](http://www.usvn.info/), [SVNManager](http://svnmanager.org/), or [svn-access-manager](http://svn-access-mana.sourceforge.net/).  I've not really used any of these tools, so I can't really comment on their usefulness.

Comment: Mainly the code review part. It's a great point to start with to understand the development process. But other parts are better to have. I'll try your recommendations. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to look at [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) as well.  I haven't used it but the LLVM team is considering it.  It supports Subversion, though you see it talking about git in a number of places.

Comment: @AlvinCao Just a reminder since you're new.  If you find my answer acceptable, you should "Accept" my answer.

Answer (score 50):

You can try using [phabricator](http://phabricator.org/). It can be used for SVN and Git. It does a lot more but it does provide code review (before) and code audit (after).

I have been evaluating Gerrit, Reviewboard and Phabricator myself and have not yet decided which way to go.

A quick summary

### Gerrit

1. Used by Android for example, so can't be bad
2. Supports only Git
3. Review is created by pushing to a special branch
4. Two methods of voting, verified (by Jenkins for example) and code review
5. After review the change can be pushed directly to the master branch by Gerrit
6. Comprehensive access control mechanism to protect the repository
7. UI not so attractive but fast, shows one file at the time
8. As it only shows one file at the time it has a nice tick box next to the files you have reviewed
9. Able to trigger Jenkins for verification of the patch
10. Written in Java (.war)
11. Very active development

### Reviewboard

1. Used by Apache for example, so can't be bad
2. Supports any modern SCM
3. Pre commit and post commits reviews are created using a Python script
4. After pre commit review you can commit your code to the repository, however this is difficult to verify and can be by passed
5. No access control mechanism for repository as it is not under its control
6. UI is nice, but very slow when loading diffs. It can take a fair bit of time on my test system to load the file differences while Gerrit and Phabricator are much faster
7. Written in Python
8. Active development

### Phabricator

Effective June 1, 2021: Phabricator is no longer actively maintained.

1. For example used by Facebook and Dropbox, so can't be bad
2. Supports Git, Subversion and Mercurial
3. Pre-commit review by using php scripts
4. Post-commit reviews (audit) can be created by making rules that will trigger an audit (nice!)
5. Is more like a complete eco system which includes a bug tracker, repo browser, wiki and more
6. They call it light hearted, heavy duty. This means you need to put up with terms like "Clowncopterize" or "Avast" instead of "OK" and you can close tasks "Out of Spite"
7. Written in php

My general impression is that Gerrit is favored by new open source projects, Reviewboard by older projects and Phabricator by new startups.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed/bulleted highlights for each.