# Gerrit equivalent for other repositories such as Clearcase/Subversion

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, clearcase, gerrit

I recently came across Gerrit Code review tool facilitating online code reviews for projects using the Git version control system. I am just wondering whether there exists something similar for other repositories such as Clearcase/subversion.

Ok so for those who don't know about Gerrit.

**Gerrit** gates code check-ins.  When developers push changes, they go into Gerrit’s code review queue.  The changes cannot be merged to master branch until they get reviewed and tested.

Humans take care of code review.  Jenkins takes care of build and unit testing.

So it goes like this:

1. Developer pushes a change to Gerrit.  It goes into the review queue.
2. Reviewers get notified that there’s a change waiting to be reviewed.
3. Jenkins also gets notified.  Jenkins retrieves the change and runs build tests for all 11 platforms.   It can also run static analysis checks, style checks, and so on.

   a.       If any builds or tests fail, Jenkins marks the change “Test Failed” in the Gerrit review.
    b.      If all builds and tests pass, Jenkins marks the change “Test Passed”.
4. If the code review passes and the tests pass, then the change may be merged into the main branch.
5. If the review or tests fail, the commit cannot be merged.  The developer must fix it up to satisfy Jenkins.

Jenksins CI server is an active review participant.As a bonus, reviewers usually can see Jenkins’ results before they even review the code.  If the change failed testing, then the reviewers don’t need to waste their time on this change yet.

So main branch always builds successfully. Isn't excellent!

I am looking for something similar for Clearcase, I already have a contnious integration build environment for Clearcase but I want to plug the functionality of Gerrit to it. Another possibility may be to just use Gerrit with Clearcase but couldn't get any pointers for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodeReviewer](http://codereviewer.org/) is a good alternative for Subversion.

But I don't know of a good review tool for ClearCase, since it is a file-by-file revision VCS, as opposed to all the others (SVN like Git) which are repository-wide revision VCS.
(See the differences in "[What are the basic clearcase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)".

That is why Gerrit wouldn't work well with ClearCase.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about ClearCase but for Subversion you might consider [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) or [ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/). Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395854/is-there-anything-for-subversion-as-gerrit-for-git/16006541#16006541)