# Does crucible integrate with teamcity

Tags: svn, teamcity, gerrit, atlassian-crucible

Does crucible integrate with teamcity?If not then what peer code review tool can be used with Teamcity for continuous integration?

Also I have another question.... does gerrit work with subversion? I saw reitveld had some support for subversion but does gerrit has the support for svn?

Comment: Perhaps you should split this question in two since you're really asking two completely different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crucible doesn't integrate directly with TeamCity, however, [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) (Atlassian's issue tracker) integrates quite nicely with both TeamCity and Crucible/FishEye.

Here are some resources for further reading:

- [JIRA + Crucible Integration](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview/code-quality-jira)
- [JIRA Plugin for TeamCity](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stiltsoft.jira.teamcity)
- [Linking JIRA to TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Integrating+TeamCity+with+Issue+Tracker)
- [Integrating JIRA with FishEye](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+FishEye)

Also, no, [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) only supports Git. [This SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395854/is-there-anything-for-subversion-as-gerrit-for-git#comment18362491_13395854) also suggests rietveld as an alternative for SVN.