# Recommendations for a good peer code review tool?

Tags: svn, git-svn, gerrit, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

I'm looking for a good peer code review tool where I can choose which users are most appropriate for my review (although others can self join), and keeps track of changes which essentially update the code in the review (in other words I don't want obsolete code to remain in the review, rather be replaced by the later version).

Essentially think along the lines of Crucible/Fisheye but 100% free and hostable in house.

I know of CodeBrag which is ok for small teams but doesn't seem to provide the sort of appropriate peer functionality I am looking for.

I also know of Gerrit but this seems to contain it's own central repo where as I already have a fully functioning central repository.

The other slight hinderance is the current use of SVN as a versioning tool. CodeBrag thankfully has git-svn support but Gerrit seems pure git (although I assume git-svn could be shoehorned in to the flow).

Answer (score 2):

Considering your requirements, Gerrit is your best choice.

1. Good peer code review tool => **Check**
2. Can choose which users are most appropriate for my review (although others can self join) => **Check**
3. Keeps track of changes which essentially update the code in the review => **Check**
4. 100% free and hostable in house => **Check**
5. Appropriate peer functionality => **Check**
6. Pure git => **Check**

Comment: Yes the awesome Gerrit

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend Gerrit. We use it together with the official cooperate approved gitlab solution for compliance. Meaning, any code that has passed the review and is merged into the branch will be automatically replicated to the centrally backed up gitlab using the replication plugin.

You can also checkout my, maybe outdated, answer here: [Is there anything for Subversion like Gerrit for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395854/is-there-anything-for-subversion-as-gerrit-for-git/16006541#16006541)